# Inaccuracy in the new users tab

Tags: bug

After the moderator election I clicked through the newly discovered user tabs and I found a little inaccuracy.

[image]

The tool tip of the tab says **users who joined in the last 45 days**. As it happens I am a 46 day site member. Yet I am still listed in the tab. Of course, this is not a big thing, I just thought to mention it anyways.

EDIT: Since the time zone might be relevant. I am currently within the UTC + 1 time zone. I noticed and took the screenshot at around 10:30.

Comment: Is this a time zone thing? Times are measured from 0:00 GMT, and generally there's a 24-hour window to allow for users between GMT-11 and GMT+14, as well (so 45 days is actually longer than 45 days).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I added some information that might be relevant.

Comment: When someone joins, does it show "member for 1 day" or "member for 0 days"? It might just be a *0-based vs 1-based* issue. Regardless of the reason, it looks humorous. Well spotted!

Comment: It's "Member for 1 day". Counting starts at 1. And there's the time-zone window. It's only ever going to be approximate!

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign], I think. Certainly the same is true on all SE sites, and it never goes higher than 46. Might be related to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155743/how-have-i-visited-on-more-days-than-ive-been-registered/167017#167017), if you've been a member for 46 separate days but less than 45 times 24 hours.

Comment: It's at least a sign that they've used multiple algorithms for calculating membership duration. Not a bug *per se*, arguably, but maybe a code smell.